# Creating a link to share that contains the password

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring, ionic-framework

I'm creating this Quiz application with Ionic and Java+Spring

Now i need to create a sort of link that i can share with other people, so they can access a specific quiz that i created.

To enter inside a quiz, you need to have the password for it.

But i'm looking for to create a sort of link that i wont need to put a password if enter inside the application from the link that i got.

I was thinking to encrypt the password and pass it inside the URL, and then decrypt it when got inside the application, but i don't know if it is the best option.

Comment: If it's just a way to access a specific quiz, you just need a unique string in the URL, the URL itself is the password, no need to encrypt it. Generating a [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) should be fine, you can just tell the user not to share it. I know a few sites that do this - like drawnames.com - granted this is only acceptable if you are not protecting sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

## If save the results of quiz

If you save the results of quiz per specific URL, Your way seems very danger.
Even if the password was encrypted and included in URL, knowing Url can access the quiz and change the results.

URL data can be hijacked by the middle-ware like proxy server or snipping.
And even it stored in the browser, so if you access URL on a public PC, the URL may be stored in the browser and exposed.

It means anyone who knows URL can modify it's result.

## If not save the results of quiz

Like Chris Hamilton mentioned in comment, If just a way to access a specific quiz, and not save the results.
Just specify url like uuid or id of the quiz.
In this case, URL data is not sensitive and it does not matter if it is exposed.